# Is echo vallid syntax in teradata BTEQ

Tags: teradata, sql-scripts

Can any one please explian me the below bteq code.

Is this script valid?

```
exec 1> $CODE/edlr2/logs/AGP_MBR_BTEQ_CSA_MBR_STG_LOAD_$(date +"%Y%m%d_%H%M%S").log 2>&1`echo "script file =" $0 PARM_FILE=$1 echo "parm file= "$PARM_FILE.parm . $CODE/edlr2/scripts/$PARM_FILE.parm select name from customer;
```

Can anyone please explain this code

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include 
the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code  necessary 
to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a **clear problem 
statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and 
Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I am not understanding this code, which is written by someone else. Can you please explain what is happening here

Comment: That's not a BTEQ script, it's a *shell script* probably creating a script which is submitted with BTEQ later

Comment: is echo bteq script command, or it is linux command. is it valid here – Can i run this query on bteq

Answer (score 0):

See: https://superuser.com/questions/436586/why-redirect-output-to-21-and-12

`exec 1> $CODE/edlr2/logs/AGP_MBR_BTEQ_CSA_MBR_STG_LOAD_$(date +"%Y%m%d_%H%M%S").log`

This writes to a log file

```
2>&1 `echo "script file =" $0 PARM_FILE=$1 echo "parm file= "$PARM_FILE.parm . $CODE/edlr2/scripts/$PARM_FILE.parm select name from customer;
```

`2>&1` points the file descriptor #2 to where #1 (above) is already pointing (the `.log` file).

However it looks like you're missing an ending grave ` somewhere above since you start one before `echo` but never close it. So I don't think that script is valid. But I also know nothing about how your database is setup to evaluate if the rest is valid. Unless you can give specific errors and information about how your files are setup and doing, it's hard to help you.

Additional info: `exec` will run a script at a location, and so part:

```
echo "script file =" $0 PARM_FILE=$1 echo "parm file= "$PARM_FILE.parm . $CODE/edlr2/scripts/$PARM_FILE.parm select name from customer;
```

is essentially running a command script and logging it to a log file. It would output and run something like:

```
script file=/var/somefile
parm file=/var/someparms.parm
. /var/anotherparmfile.parm select name from customer;
```

[What is exec](https://askubuntu.com/questions/525767/what-does-an-exec-command-do)

[What is a dot command](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/114300/whats-the-meaning-of-a-dot-before-a-command-in-shell)

Comment: is echo  bteq script command, or it is linux command. is it valid here

Comment: `echo` is a common term in many languages and systems, in this case it looks to be a bash / terminal command due to the fact that it's being used with the `1>` and `2>&1`

Comment: Then this is not parsed by bteq?  If i run this

Comment: @XYZ No, everything "echo'd" out will just be run by the terminal. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

As is, it is neither a unix script, nor some `code`, nor something bteq could use.

My guess would be, your 'script' looks like this (dismissed the lonely ` as typing error)

```
exec 1> $CODE/edlr2/logs/AGP_MBR_BTEQ_CSA_MBR_STG_LOAD_$(date +"%Y%m%d_%H%M%S").log 2>&1
echo "script file =" $0
PARM_FILE=$1 
echo "parm file= "$PARM_FILE.parm 
. $CODE/edlr2/scripts/$PARM_FILE.parm select name from customer;
```

As @Xander already guessed it would redirect output to a log-file and print info about script and logfile name and then execute the script `$PARM_FILE.parm` with some parameters.

Further guessing, because BTEQ is mentioned in the name for the log file, in that `.parm` script bteq may be used to execute a SQL-command which is passed to it as parameters.

`bteq` needs a logon command. If that is added in the `.parm` script, before the concatenated parameters, and that passed to bteq, you may get some meaningfull response.

Be aware, that the `;` at the end would never be passed to the script. The shell would take it as `end of command` token. And the `.parm` script would have to add the `;` too to construct a valied SQL-command.

Why a dot-command is used to execute a script, which is named `.parm` is beyond my imagination.